# How to solve "Missing $ inserted" error?

Tags: errors

Here is my LaTeX code block..

It's combination of formula and sentences.

If I run it, an error always occurs: "Missing $ inserted" in that part (code block part).

```
 \begin{itemize}
 \item
 \begin{singlespace}
 \begin{verbatim}
  se=strel('disk',9);
  citra_dilasi=imdilate(cropped_img,se);
  \end{verbatim}
  \end{singlespace}

  The morphological dilation is performed to "\emph{cropped_img}" with the SE    
  (structuring element), where the SE is a disk-shaped structuring element and the 
  radius is 9. \emph{cropped_img} is the image that has crop horizontally.
```

The error is like this.
[image: Error Messege]

How to solve it??

Comment: Please show more for the MWE. This does not show where you end itemize, etc.

Comment: You can't just use `_` in text since it's a math-mode directive to initiate subscripts. Use `\textunderscore`.